# pass by value for array in java

Tags: java

I have a code as follows

```
public static int mat(final int a[]) {
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        a[i]=a[i]+10;
    System.out.println("Mat Function");
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    return 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};

    mat(arr);
    System.out.println("Main");
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

My main must show values 1,2,3,4,5,6 and mat function must show 11,12,13,14,15,16. But both are showing 11,12,13,14,15,16. How to rectify this and pass array by value to the function.

Comment: what is `matt` in your main

Comment: @amitbhardwaj: It was a typo for `arr`, I'm sure - I fixed it at the same time as fixing the indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never pass an array *object* at all. You pass an array *reference*, which is always going to be passed by value.

If you want to create a copy of the array, then pass a reference to that copy to the method, the simplest approach is probably to call `clone`:

```
mat(arr.clone());
```

Note that calling `clone()` on an array always makes a *shallow* clone - irrelevant here, but if you had a `Person[]` for example, it wouldn't create a copy of each `Person` referred to by the original array... so changes to the cloned array (e.g. `clonedArray[0] = new Person()`) wouldn't be seen by the calling code, but changes to the objects referred to by the array (e.g. `clonedArray[1].setName("Fred")`) would be seen via the original array, because the two arrays would refer to the same objects.

As a side note, I'd strongly recommend keeping the type information in one place for variables, e.g. `int[] arr` rather than `int arr[]`. I'd also recommend using braces for `if`, `for`, and `while` statements even when the body is only a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in your main method you meant to print the `arr` array (the same one passed to the `mat` method) and not `matt` (which is never defined anywhere), the `mat` method changes the content of that array, and therefore main prints the updated array.

If you wish your `mat` method not to change that array, create a new array :

```
public static int mat(final int a[])
{
    int[] a2 = new int[a.length];
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        a2[i]=a[i]+10;
    System.out.println("Mat Function");
    for(int i=0;i<a2.length;i++)
        System.out.println(a2[i]);
    return 1;
}
```